# Кодировка imap_search PHP

Tags: php, кодировка

Когда я пытаюсь искать латинские символы - всё нормально. Но если я хочу искать кириллицу - выдает непарвильный результат либо вообще не выдает результат. Я выставил кодировку как аргумент функции

```
imap_search($inbox,'TEXT "кириллица"',SE_FREE,"utf-8");
```

но это тоже не помогло.

Comment: Можно попробовать указать кодировку как `UTF-8`. И кстати, вы точно уверены что сервер понимает UTF-8, а не работает в другой кодировке?

Comment: Пробовал, не работает большими буквами. Пытаюсь парсить gmail, не знаю как проверить какую кодировку он использует

Comment: Еще как вариант можно попробовать `UTF8` - вроде бы как gmail такую кодировку должен понимать